# Retrieve data from dataset

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select StudentID,StudentName from StudentMaster where StudentID = '" + start + "'", conn);              
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds,"StudentMaster");
SqlDataAdapter db = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Registration_No from Candidate_Registration where StudentID='" + start + "'", conn);
db.Fill(ds, "Candidate_Registration");
```

Here 'start' is a textbox value of a textbox in previous form i.e form2. 
I want to fetch StudentName and StudentID from StudentMaster where StudentID = start.
The table is named 'StudentMaster'.
Fill the dataset with StudentMaster.
Then I want to fetch Registration_No from Candidate_Registration where StudentID=start.
The table is named 'Candidate_Registration'.
Fill the dataset with Candidate_Registration.
Now according to the 'Registration_No' that is fetched, I want to fetch 'CourseID' from 'Registered_Courses'.
But, the problem is, how to access the fetched 'Registration_No' i.e. how to put it in the following query:
if I can take the fetched Registration_No into a variable named 'reg_no' then,
"Select CourseID from Registered_Courses where Registration_No="+ reg_no;

For more understanding I mention the tables and the relationships....

```
StudentMaster
-------------
StudentID Primary key,
StudentName

Candidate_Registration
----------------------
Registration_No Foreign key,
ExamID Foreign key,
StudentID Foreign key,
Seat_No,
Primary key(Registration_No,ExamID)

Registered_Courses
------------------
Registration_No Primary key,
ExamID Foreign key,
CourseID Foreign key,

Course_Master
-------------
CourseID Primary key,
Course_Name,
Description
```

i.e. finally I want to get the Course_Name for a particular StudentID.

Can anyone please help me out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should really use parameterized query

Answer (score 1):

Try this query :

```
Select StudentMaster.StudentId, Course_Master.Course_Name from StudentMaster 
INNER JOIN Candidate_Registration 
ON Candidate_Registration.StudentId = StudentMaster.StudentId 
INNER JOIN Registered_Courses 
ON Registered_Courses.Registration_No = Candidate_Registration.Registration_No AND Registered_Courses.ExamID = Candidate_Registration.ExamID 
INNER JOIN Course_Master 
ON Course_Master.CourseID = Registered_Courses.CourseID
WHERE StudentMaster.StudentId = @MyId
```

Replace @MyId with your Id parameter and it gives you all the CourseNames for a StudentId.

Comment: Thanks 4 d answer, but when I apply it, an error "Ambiguous Column StudentID" is encountered at runtime on the line "da.Fill(ds,"StudentMaster");"

Comment: @user463493 : Edited the query, there was a StudentMaster missing in the WHERE clause :)